# mongoDB Find by id and return subdocument matched

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have this Collection:

```
    {
     _id:0,
     user_id: 12,
     list: [{_.id:0, name:"john"},{_.id:1, name:"hanna"}]
    },
    {
     _id:1,
     user_id: 22,
     list: [{_.id:0, name:"john"},{_.id:1, name:"hanna"}]
    }
```

I want to query the collection like this: find the document by `user_id`
and return only `{_.id:0, name:"john"}` inside `list`
couldnt find any clue how to do that

some example for better explanation this what I want to achive:

```
const johnDoc = findOne({user_id:0}).list.findOne({name:"john"})
```

I know its not valid only for explaining what I want to achive.

Comment: how it will select user from list on the base of `user_id`? there is 12 and 22 in user_id but not in `list` array.

Comment: in list I want to find by the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `$unwind`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      user_id: 12,
      "list.name": "john"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$list"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      user_id: 12,
      "list.name": "john"
    }
  },
  
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HFsMc9Vdjtx)

Comment: You could also add as the last stage "{$replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$list" } }" to replace the root document with the nested document.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aggregation operator in find's projection from MongoDB 4.4,

- `$filter` to iterate loop of `list` and find matching user by `name` property
- `$first` to select the first element from filtered result

```
db.collection.find({
  user_id: 12
},
{
  list: {
    $first: {
      $filter: {
        input: "$list",
        cond: {
          $eq: [
            "$$this.name",
            "john"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Aq0Io9YxO_x)